Request oauth/token no accept redirect uri only take for database
I upgrade my app from laravel 5.6 to 10 so I upgraded passport to 11, when I cosume http://localhost:8080/oauth/token I get this error:
400 bad request:
\"hint\":\"Invalid redirect URI\",\"message\":\"The request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value, includes a parameter more than once, or is otherwise malformed.\"
but if I remove the redirect_uri field it works,the value of redirect_uri is the same in the database
$http = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
        
$response = $http->post($app['oauth_token'], [
    'form_params' => [
                'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
                'client_id' => $app['oauth_key'],
                'client_secret' => $app['oauth_secret'],
                'redirect_uri' => $app['oauth_callback'],
                'code' => $code,
            ],
     ]);

I don't want to removed or I don't know if that could be a problem.
Appreciate your help!
